# How to increase a function variable each time the function is run

Tags: python

doing an alpha vantage api pull for stock data. in my code below, there are three variables in the api pull: fastperiod, slowperiod, and matype. i'm trying to figure out a way to run this function over and over again, each time those three variables change for the next pull. the matype can be an integer between 0-8. fastperiod and slowperiod can be an integer between 1-100. so theoretically, this thing would run over and over again, with those variables changing each time, until all possible variations of those three variables were exhausted.

any suggestions?

```
def get_ppo_close_8():
    pull_parameters = {
        'function': 'PPO',
        'symbol': stock,
        'interval': interval,
        'series_type': 'close',
        'fastperiod': 12,
        'slowperiod': 26,
        'matype': 8,
        'datatype': 'json',
        'apikey': key
    }
    pull = rq.get(url, params=pull_parameters)
    data = pull.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Technical Analysis: PPO'], orient='index', dtype=float)
    df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
    df.columns = ['Date', 'PPO Close 8']
    df.insert(0, 'Stock', stock)
    return df.tail(past_years * annual_trading_days)
```

Comment: use `def get_ppo_close_8(fastperiod, slowperiod, matype)` and run with different values (run function in some `for`-loops). Or use `for`-loops directly inside function.

Comment: perfect. thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1: easily understandable**

Use a nested for loop to iterate through all combination of your input variables. I've also modified the ranges assuming you actually want the values starting from 1

```
for matype in range(1,9):
    for slowperiod in range(1,101):
        for fastperiod in range(1,101):
            get_ppo_close_8(matype, slowperiod, fastperiod)
```

**METHOD 2: itertools (from sal below https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245884/9510611)**

```
matype = range(1,9) 
slowperiod = range(1,101) 
fastperiod = range(1,101)

# product will make a generator that will produce all triplets 
combinations = product(matype, slowperiod, fastperiod) 

# efficiently use them in your function 
for matype, slowperiod, fastperiod in combinations: 
    get_ppo_close_8(matype, slowperiod, fastperiod)
```

Comment: sure. was trying to do that. how do iterate through all combinations of those three variables and automatically change the variable number each time it's ran? that's where i'm having a hard time. thoughts?

Comment: ah, yes! i think that may do it. such a simple answer. lol. usually is.

Comment: Haha yeah, it usually is! If this answer was helpful mark is as answered

Comment: hey! real quick, how would you nest this in a while loop? what would that look like? i've used while loops, but never in this context.

Comment: Oh sorry I should re-edit this, you wont need a while loop with this method, it will finish when the it has gone through all combinations

Answer (score 2):

To speed things up you can use `itertools.product()`. For your specific case it would look something like:

```
    from itertools import product

    def get_ppo_close_8(matype, slowperiod, fastperiod):
        # Replace the print with your code here
        print(">>>", matype, slowperiod, fastperiod)

    # define your ranges
    matype = range(8)
    slowperiod = range(100)
    fastperiod = range(100)

    # product will make a generator that will produce all triplets
    combinations = product(matype, slowperiod, fastperiod)

    # efficiently use them in your function
    for item in combinations:
        get_ppo_close_8(*item)  # use '*' to unpack
```